# Spyder Proxy Settings

Tags: python, proxy, spyder, mnist

I am trying to use Spyder for Python/Tensorflow within a company's network. Unfortunately I cannot disable the Firewall, which brings some Proxy problems with it.

Using this very basic code

```
import tensorflow as tf
learn = tf.contrib.learn
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset('mnist')
```

throws following error

*File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open raise URLError(err)*

URLError: < urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed >

Setting environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy does lead to the same problem.

**Is there any way to edit proxy settings in Spyder directly? If not: how do I adjust the proxy in python?**

```
import urllib2
proxy_user='xxx'
proxy_password='xxx'
proxy_ip='proxy.company:8080'
proxy_url = 'http://' + proxy_user + ':' + proxy_password + '@' + proxy_ip
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":proxy_url})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support,urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

throws following error

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'*

Thanks in advance,
Johnny

Comment: If you're using Python 3, I think you need to change `urllib2` to `urllib3`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Carlos!

Unfortunately, analogue to urllib2, the program outputs ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'

Comment: Found a working solution:

not only setting http_proxy for user's environment variable but for system's plus executing Spyder as administrator
both is required, but it is working for me!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open

- Anaconda Prompt as Administrator
- Add proxy settings in conda using command: `conda config --set proxy_servers.https "proxy.company.com:8080"`

Your proxy settings are now ready to be used in `Conda` environment. Also, you can run your python code from `Conda` prompt.